# Meanjs name of data variable?

Tags: mean-stack

I'm trying to understand the mean stack, so in the following part of the meanjs code, what is the variable that contains the whole data pulled from DB (is it articles?). Thank you.
/myApp/public/modules/controllers/articles.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Articles',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $filter, Authentication, Articles) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        $scope.create = function() {
            var article = new Articles({
                title: this.title,
                content: this.content
            });
            article.$save(function(response) {
                $location.path('articles/' + response._id);
            });

            this.title = '';
            this.content = '';
        };

        $scope.remove = function(article) {
            if (article) {
                article.$remove();

                for (var i in $scope.articles) {
                    if ($scope.articles[i] === article) {
                        $scope.articles.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $scope.article.$remove(function() {
                    $location.path('articles');
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.update = function() {
            var article = $scope.article;
            if (!article.updated) {
                article.updated = [];
            }
            article.updated.push(new Date().getTime());

            article.$update(function() {
                $location.path('articles/' + article._id);
            });
        };

        $scope.find = function() {
            Articles.query(function(articles) {
                $scope.articles = articles;
            });
        };

        $scope.findOne = function() {
            Articles.get({
                articleId: $stateParams.articleId
            }, function(article) {
                $scope.article = article;
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create, Remove, Update and find are all a little bit different. On create there is no object from the database because you are creating it at the moment of that function. In the other three functions the article does come from the database.

Aside from watching this tutorial on meanjs : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHpMH_5n2fQ (opposed to mean.io) You can also do some research into what a CRUD application is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what schoeffman said, there are two functions here that do pull data from the database, $scope.find() and $scope.findOne().

If you call find(), it will return an array with all of the 'Article' objects in the database table. So for instance, if you wanted to list all of the articles that have ever been posted, you would call find(), and then the articles would be stored in $scope.articles.

Similarly, if you call findOne with a given id, it will store the object of that particular article in $scope.article.

The examples included in the boilerplate call these functions inside of data-ng-init in the view (check out line 1 in list-articles.client.view.html or view-article.client.view.html to see what I'm talking about.)

If $scope is confusing you, I would watch this vid: [Angular in 60-ish minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM).